# Recyclerview not scrolling to the left in tablet landscape mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, tablet, landscape

Got stuck in this issue for a while. I have this recyclerview inside a frament with horizontal layoutmanager. Scrolling on both side (left and right) is working in phone (portait mode) but on tablet (landscape mode) it only scrolls to the right. Here's my layout btw:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".fragments.FragmentSubscriptionPlanList">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/change_plan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/rvSubscription"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/rvSubscription"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/rvSubscription"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/rvSubscription"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSubscription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jpyG.png) since SO won't allow me to embed image here yet:

Comment: `Can you please embed a screenshot to show us what the result looks like?`

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I already added a link for the screenshot of layout. Thanks!